# In the following fragment, is the & a bitwise or logical operator? why?

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

In the following fragment, is the & a bitwise or logical operator? why?

```
boolean a, b;
//      
if (a & b)...
```

Comment: True and false in Java are logical values, not numbers. `&` on booleans is a logical operator. But people often refer to it as "bitwise &" anyway, to distinguish it from `&&`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you regard booleans as single-bit numbers, then `&` on booleans is consistent with a bitwise operation.

Java regards true and false as logical values, not numbers, so I would say that `&` on booleans is a logical operator, not a bitwise operator. But people often refer to it as "bitwise &", to distinguish it from `&&`.